# series of equicontinuous functions and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of equicontinuous functions on some compact interval $[a,b]$. Assume that we have pointwise convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_{n}(x)=F(x)$$ for some function $F$ defined on $[a,b]$. I would like to see an example of this situation where the convergence is NOT uniform and $F$ is continuous. I have taken $f_{n}(x)=(-1)^{n}x/n$ hoping to use somehow the conditional convergence to some constant multiple of $x$, which is clearly continuous, to infer non uniform convergence, but I am not sure the example to work?

Comment: For $f_n(x) = (-1)^nx/n$ the convergence is uniform. Strategy: take a sequence $(g_n)$ of continuous functions that converges pointwise, but not uniformly to $0$. See whether the sequence given by $f_n = g_n - g_{n-1}$ (where $g_{-1} = 0$) is equicontinuous.

Comment: If on top of Daniel's comment, the sequence $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly bounded... You're  sure to win according to [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem)!

Comment: This construction would give a sequence of equicontinuous functions on a compact set converging not uniformly. This is impossible, by exercise 16 page 168 on W. Rudin's book. Examples like this one can not work by this reason. Ascoli-Arzelà implies uniform convergence moreover. Unless I am missing something

Comment: @Hair80 If $\{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is equicontinuous, then the family of partial sums $s_k = \sum_{n \leqslant k} f_n$ need not be equicontinuous. For the most obvious examples of that, the series won't converge, or won't converge to a continuous function. Thus I suggest starting from the other end. Take a sequence of continuous functions that converges non-uniformly to $0$, and see if you can pick a sequence such that the family of differences is equicontinuous.